# Rsync: provide a list of unsent files

Tags: rsync

The Rsync `-u` flag prevents the overwriting of modified destination files. How can I get a list of files that were not sent due to this flag? The `-v` flag will let me know which files *were* sent, but I would like to know which ones *weren't*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [rsync man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> ```
> -i, --itemize-changes
> ```
>
> Requests a simple itemized list of the changes  that  are  being
>                 made to each file, including attribute changes.  This is exactly
>                 the same as specifying --out-format='%i %n%L'.   **If  you  repeat
>                 the option, unchanged files will also be output**, but only if the
>                 receiving rsync is at least version 2.6.7 (**you can use -vv  with
>                 older  versions  of  rsync**, but that also turns on the output of
>                 other verbose messages).

In my testing, the `-ii` option isn't working with rsync 3.0.8, but `-vv` is.  Your mileage may vary.

You could also get substantially the same information by invoking rsync with `--dry-run` and `--existing` in the opposite direction.  So if your regular transfer looked like this:

```
rsync --update --recursive local:/directory/ remote:/directory/
```

You would use:

```
rsync --dry-run --existing --recursive remote:/directory/ local:/directory/
```

but `-vv` or `-ii` is safer and less prone to misinterpretation.